# How to use multithreading to solve sudoku-like puzzle in scala?

Tags: multithreading, scala, sudoku

I'm wondering how to best use multithreading to solve a sort-of sudoku puzzle in Scala. What I start with is a 2D array, made into a 1D array for easier traversing. Every element in the array consists of a Square class, which holds all possible options for that square. I have already obtained the options by reducing from what already exists on the board.

What I do next is using recursion, moving from square to square in > direction from x(0, 0) to x(n, n). I try each option in each square, and if a square is out of options to try, it returns to a previous square that has more options.

This DOES work, but it goes really slow for puzzles over 10 x 10. I was thinking using multi threading might speed up the process? Am I somehow able to introduce multi threading into my current solution? If not, how could I best use multi threading to speed up the progress of solving the sudoku-like puzzle.

```
def next(Squares: Array[Square], step: Int): Unit = {

  val sq: _Square = SQs(i)

  for (o <- sq.options) { // check each o in square options
    val valid = isValidValue(SQs, sq, o) // scan row/column to check if option is valid
    if (valid) {
      sq.value = o // sets value of square to option
      next(Squares, step + 1) // use recursion to step into next square in squares
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example of a 4x4 puzzle:

```
__ __ __<__
 A
__  1 __ __
 A
__ __>__ __

 1 __ __ __
```

and the solution

```
 2  4  1< 3
 A         
 3  1  4  2
 A         
 4  3> 2  1
           
 1  2  3  4
```

Comment: The first thing to do is to avoid using mutable data, which makes parallel algorithms much harder.

Comment: How would I go about making the data immutable? I am very new to Scala/Java and this whole concept eludes me...

Comment: Instead of updating the existing global model, create a new model with the updated state and pass that to the recursive function. Since each call works on its own copy of the model you can have multiple threads running the same code on different versions of the model (different starting points). But this is really outside the scope of a stackoverflow question.